# injection of service is failed

Tags: java, spring-boot

I m trying to send an email using a service class, but I always receive null .I can't see my mistake

here is my code
this my notification service

```
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;
/*
@Autowired
public  NotificationService(JavaMailSender javaMailSender){
    this.javaMailSender = javaMailSender;

}
*/
@Async
public void sendNotificaitoin(String msg) throws MailException, InterruptedException {

    System.out.println("Sleeping now...");
    Thread.sleep(10000);

    System.out.println("Sending email...");

    SimpleMailMessage mail = new SimpleMailMessage();
    mail.setTo("ghanem.dhafer@gmail.com");
    mail.setFrom("ulquiorra.cifer19924@gmail.com");
    mail.setSubject("NOTIFICATION");
    mail.setText(msg);
    javaMailSender.send(mail);

    System.out.println("Email Sent!");
```

this is where I invoke the service:

```
@Autowired
private NotificationService notificationService;
try {

    notificationService.sendNotificaitoin(msg);
    }catch( Exception e ){
        // catch error
        System.out.println("Error Sending Email: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

i also create beans, all tuto shows sending email in controller but i need to send in a service(class).
any ideas?

Comment: Print the stack trace, and you'll know where the exception is thrown.

Comment: An `@Autowired` dependency cannot be `null`. It can only be `null` if you create an instance of the service yourself. Show some actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Put the JavaMailSender in a class and annotate it with @Service like

```
@Service
JavaMailSender {
        void sendNotification();
}
```

Then use it in another class like

```
@Autowired
JavaMailSender notificationService;

// use the service in a method
void somewhere(){
        notificationService.sendNotification(yourArguments);
}
```

Comment: this is similar for what I tried to did, creating service and call it in other class...what's the difference?